# action menu com radio button

Tags: java, android

Estou tendo problemas com esse código, eu quero com que os radio buttons apareça para escolha em um popup após apertar em parâmetros, só que não está acontecendo isso,

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
   inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_desequilibrio, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.desequilibrio_parametros:
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Esse switch está estranho. Sua idéia é realmente retornar `true` e encerrar a execução do método? Pois se você observar bem, sempre que esse método retornar `true`, o bloco dentro da cláusula `default` não será executado.

Comment: Obrigado, consegui resolver, foi falta de atenção minha.